# "//Print a message" error in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

This is the code in pyCharm app on Linux Ubuntu

```
#1/usr/bin/python

def main(msg):
    //Print a Message
    print(msg)

main("Hello People")
```

I keep getting an error.

This is the video course I am following:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBp0Rb-ZJak

At the 3:37:00 mark is where it's supposed to refresh, but because of my error it will not.

Here is a screenshot of the code and error. 
http://s1227.photobucket.com/user/MrGHLover/media/Screenshot%20from%202017-09-10%2023-36-52.png.html?sort=3&o=0

It is the same in the video but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Kindly give the error message in the description instead of screenshot link.

Comment: That is not how you comment in Python

Answer (score 1):

Commenting by '//' is not allowed in python. Use '#' for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

You can comment a line in Python using `#`. Or you can (kind of) create a multi-line comment using `'''<some long string>""".`//` Isn't valid Python.